# How can I fix this issue about JQuery Date Picker?

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

When I tried to get a datepicker for my Yii2 activeform, I've tried JQuery DatePicker to get a better result. However, after I tried the "two-ways" binding method, it appeared a problem called "datepicker is not a function". Why is it? And how can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

```
// vuejs to catch date picker for school end date
    var elm = new Vue({
        el: '#Education',
        data: {
            date: '08/2018',
        },
        mounted () {
            var vm = this
            $('#cand_school_yearE').datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText) {
                    vm.date = dateText
                },
            });
        },
    })
```

`$(function(){
    $("input[name=cand_school_yearE]" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy'
    });
});`

I expect the datepicker can work perfectly and bind it to a form as this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji6Qp.png

Comment: Are u sure the `datepicker` script is loaded before the vue component is `mounted`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get jquery-ui.js loaded before your javascript in order to get the datepicker function

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/